# Windows phone 8 back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows-phone-8, navigation, angular-ui-router

I am developing an app using angularjs and angular ui router. I have found that the url fragment navigation has serious issues with ie mobile on windows phone 8. Changing states within the app works fine, but when the back button is pressed, the app always returns to the homepage. How could I get the windows phone 8 to respond well to url fragments when using the back button?

The app navigation goes:
app/#/home -> app/#/page1 -> app/#/page2
using the back button at this point would make the browser go to app/ or app/#/home rather than app/#/page1

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone (Since Windows Phone 7.1) , You can remove or change your BackStack (when you click on the back button)

You can read more about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394012(v=vs.105).aspx) (MSDN Website)

For your application, 
When you arrived on your  app/#/page2, you can remove the stackHistory.

And, when user click on the back button you can redirect him on your home page app/#/home.

```
// JavaScript Code
// addEventListener syntax for attach to the back Key press.
hardwareButtons.addEventListener("backpressed", onBackPressed);
```